# R data.table condition within group, but recorded at first instance in group

Tags: r, data.table

I have data that looks a bit like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,2),rep(3,2),4), TYPE=c(1,3,2,4,1,2,2,3,2),
                 SEQUENCE=c(seq(1,4),1,2,1,2,1))

ID  TYPE  SEQUENCE
1   1     1
1   3     2
1   2     3
1   4     4
2   1     1
2   2     2
3   2     1
3   3     2
4   2     1
```

I know need to check if a certain type is present in each ID block (binary), but only record the
answer in the first record per block (SEQUENCE == 1).

The best I came up with so far is coding them in the row they are present in, e.g.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT$A[DT$TYPE==1] <- 1
DT$B[DT$TYPE==2] <- 1
DT$C[DT$TYPE==3] <- 1
DT$D[DT$TYPE==4] <- 1
DT[is.na(DT)] <- 0
```

RESULT:

```
ID  TYPE  SEQUENCE  A B C D
1   1     1         1 0 0 0
1   3     2         0 0 1 0
1   2     3         0 1 0 0
1   4     4         0 0 0 1
2   1     1         1 0 0 0
2   2     2         0 1 0 0
3   2     1         0 1 0 0
3   3     2         0 0 1 0
4   2     1         0 1 0 0
```

However, the result should look like this:

```
ID  TYPE  SEQUENCE  A B C D
1   1     1         1 1 1 1
1   3     2         0 0 0 0
1   2     3         0 0 0 0
1   4     4         0 0 0 0
2   1     1         1 1 0 0
2   2     2         0 0 0 0
3   2     1         0 1 1 0
3   3     2         0 0 0 0
4   2     1         0 1 0 0
```

I assume this can be done with `data.table`, but I haven't quite found the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes one copy of the data.table:

```
DT[, FAC := factor(TYPE, labels=LETTERS[1:4])]

DT <- dcast.data.table(DT, ID+TYPE+SEQUENCE~FAC, fun.aggregate=length)
DT[,LETTERS[1:4] := lapply(.SD, 
                           function(x) c(any(as.logical(x)), rep(0L, length(x)-1))),
   .SDcols=LETTERS[1:4], by=ID]
#   ID TYPE SEQUENCE A B C D
#1:  1    1        1 1 1 1 1
#2:  1    2        3 0 0 0 0
#3:  1    3        2 0 0 0 0
#4:  1    4        4 0 0 0 0
#5:  2    1        1 1 1 0 0
#6:  2    2        2 0 0 0 0
#7:  3    2        1 0 1 1 0
#8:  3    3        2 0 0 0 0
#9:  4    2        1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: very neat, what exactly is the meaning of `rep(0L, length(x)-1)`

Comment: Repeat an integer zero `length(x)-1` times.