# R using 'FAC' as value column data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some old `data.table` code that now gives me error messages. The problem is described here:

[R data.table condition within group, but recorded at first instance in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403341/r-data-table-condition-within-group-but-recorded-at-first-instance-in-group)

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,2),rep(3,2),4), TYPE=c(1,3,2,4,1,2,2,3,2),
                 SEQUENCE=c(seq(1,4),1,2,1,2,1))

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[, FAC := factor(TYPE, labels=LETTERS[1:4])]

DT <- dcast.data.table(DT, ID+TYPE+SEQUENCE~FAC, fun.aggregate=length)
DT[,LETTERS[1:4] := lapply(.SD, 
                           function(x) c(any(as.logical(x)), rep(0L, length(x)-1))),
   .SDcols=LETTERS[1:4], by=ID]
```

Now this is throwing the following error:

```
Using 'FAC' as value column, Use 'value.var' to override.
```

I'm not sure if this actually affects my results or if this is just a warning

Comment: What is your version of `data.table`? Also, please add a reproducible example, as I don't get any error with the (I think) same data.table you use in the other post.

Comment: I can't reproduce this neither. You should probably just update your `data.table` version.

Comment: Version 1.9.4, R version 3.1.1

Comment: Update to the development version [on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). If you can't reproduce this anymore, it means that this bug was fixed and we can close this now.

Comment: I'm working on a secure server, so am only allowed to link to CRAN.

Comment: It's a message, not an error. And the message is quite clear. You've not provided a value to `value.var` argument. Therefore, it has picked `FAC` as the column. If you don't want the message, provide a value to `value.var` argument.